# Adding strings in JavaScript "1" + - "2" == "1-2"

Tags: javascript, string, operators

I accidentally typed the following JavaScript statement `"1" + - "2"` and I have the result `"1-2"`.
I am not sure why the minus sign was treated as a string rather than causing a syntax error.

I tried to search, but I did not get the answer I wanted.

Why the minus sign was treated as a string? it there online reference I can look at? thanks

Comment: Note that `"1" + + "2"` is also valid (returns `"12"`), but `"1" ++ "2"` is a syntax error because the `++` operator is not the same as two `+` operators in a row. And something silly like `"1" + - + - "2"` is valid too...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple: `- "2"` evaluates to `-2` because unary `-` coerces its operand to a number, which is precisely [the behavior defined in the ECMA-262 spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7)

> ### 11.4.7 Unary `-` Operator
>
> The unary `-` operator converts its operand to `Number` type and then negates it. Note that negating `+0` produces `−0`, and negating `−0` produces `+0`.
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* `: -` *UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *expr* be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Let *oldValue* be [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)([GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*expr*)).
> 3. If *oldValue* is **NaN**, return **NaN**.
> 4. Return the result of negating *oldValue*; that is, compute a Number with the same magnitude but opposite sign.

Then it's just a matter of string concatenation: `"1" + (-2)` evaluates, unsurprisingly, to `"1-2"`. By this point it should comes as no surprise that the `+` is a string concatenation (and not an addition) operator in the context because [that's what the spec says.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)

---

### TL;DR

Because, as always, that's the behavior [required by the spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Answer (score 16):

The original

```
"1" + - "2"
```

Is parsed as

```
"1" + ( - "2" )
```

The `-` here converts the `"2"` to a number and negates it, so `- "2"` evaluates to `-2`. So this becomes:

```
"1" + (-2)
```

Here, the `+` causes the `-2` to be converted to a string, `"-2"`, and then does simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Unary `-` operator (-x) has precedence over binary `+` operator (x + y).

So `"1" + - "2"`  is actually parsed as `"1" + -2`, which in turn is parsed as a string concactenation `"1" + "-2"`, to finally rsult in `"1-2"`.